# How to find out why wordpress blog is loading so slow

Tags: wordpress, dreamhost

We have a Wordpress [blog](http://blog.faro.com/) that takes between 10 - 45 seconds to load. I've backed up the site and the database, updated the plugins (and the Wordpress version), and all to no avail.

I'm trying to find out if the issue is with the blog itself or the host (dreamhost). Before contacting dreamhost I'd like to alleviate all issues on my end first.

Any pointers or advice on how to find out the cause of a slow wordpress blog?

Edit: The backend admin panel also has *very* long load times when simply navigating the UI between various screens. Not sure if that points the issue towards the host more-so than the content on the blog since the content may not play that big of a role in page load times on the admin panel?

Comment: First, your page is very large. I's aprox 5mb. You should try to optimize images to reduce page size.
Second, it's probably some host issue, since initial request takes 12 seconds to complete.
I think you should contact host support and try to problem resolve with them

Comment: Quick Fixes: merge and minify your CSS/JS so you are only loading 1-2 files in header/footer. Get a cache plugin and configure it. Definitely contact your host.

Comment: A good tool to evaluate what make your website is [Google Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=fr&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.faro.com%2F). As onedevteam said, you should optimize your images, but it seems your server is pretty slow to respond to any request. I suggest to contact your hosting provider.

Comment: Images are a big drain on page speed, you're loading images that are 300x300 but only displaying them at 65x65, the browser has to work to resize them. Use Chrome's developer tools which have Googles PageSpeed service built in.

Comment: I added an Edit to the original post with some more information that may help narrow the issue down.

Answer (score 1):

You can always test page speed with Google's [Page speed insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.faro.com).

By your blog's result, you should first reduce your image sizes.
You can do this with photo editing softwares like Photoshop or online tools like [kraken](https://kraken.io).
In Photoshop you can do this by File->Save for web.

Next issue is server response time. To reduce server response server need to process less php. Caching helps this issue. You can install [wp-super-cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/). This plugin also helps many other features which helps in optimizing your site. ( Server response time also depends upon many other factors. Refer [this](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/Server). )

For css and js minification you can use [Autoptimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/).

You also can add your scripts just before `</body>` instead of `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

I would venture to guess that your media library is huge; not only with the amount of pictures but the sizes of them. To run at optimal speeds, you should pretty much edit those photos before they go on the site so they are closer to the desired display size. Having a lot of pictures in there at 1,000px plus can cause the site to load very slowly.

Comment: I should state that the backend dashboard also has *very* long delays simply navigating the admin panel. Not sure if that helps narrow the issue down to the blog's content, or the host provider.

Comment: @mariocatch, I'm not sure that would narrow down the issue. The admin panel still needs to load everything that is in your media library regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [P3 (Plugin Performance Profiler)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/) to examine the impact of plugins ( and WP core ) on your site's load time. You will be unpleasantly surprised when you realize that some plugins do not care about performance at all ( for example only one plugin like NextgenGallery can take up to 60% of load time ).